# How do I 0-link any item?

Tags: path-of-exile

[image]

I'd like to remove the socket links from this item, and return it to 0 links.  However, I can't figure out a way to 0-link the item, so to speak.  The crafting bench only offers recipes for two-socket to three-socket crafting, so socket crafting my way to 0 links is impossible.  There is no fusing recipe for "0 linked sockets", so there's no way to do that.

In any case, how do I 0-link this item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not believe that Orbs of Fusing are able to give you a completely unlinked item, but there is still a way to get it.

1.Use orbs of fusing until the top two sockets are not linked.

2.Using the crafting bench, craft 2 sockets onto the item. Your item should now be two unlinked sockets.

3.Craft the item back up to the amount of sockets you want. Sockets gained in this fashion should always be unlinked.

Keep in mind that an item with 5 sockets already 5 linked, or 6 sockets already 6 linked, cannot have their links undone with a fusing orb. Drop the item down to 3 sockets with the bench first, then you can start using fusings.

Comment: Pretty sure the crafting bench can unlink fully-linked 5- and 6-socket items without having to remove the sockets themselves, too. Not inclined to test it at the moment, though; if you’re unlinking a 6-link there’s something very dubious about your plans.

Comment: The crafting bench can indeed do so, in my last paragraph I even mention using the bench to lower those sorts of items' links. I had only mentioned that fusing orbs would not do the job.

Comment: I mean that you don’t have to use the crafting bench to remove sockets in order to break up the links, you can just use the “X linked sockets” crafts directly. The current implication is that those crafts—which cost Fusings, notably—don’t work until you use one of the Jeweler’s-based crafts to change the number of sockets.

Comment: as the other answer says, orbs of fusing CAN completely unlink an item. and it has happened to me several times

Answer (score 3):

Since there is no crafting recipe to get zero links, the only way to achieve this is by using orbs of fusing. Orbs of fusing have a random chance to disconnect all sockets from each other.